# Why aren't my parent callbacks firing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, single-table-inheritance

I've got the following pair of models in a rails app. They're implemented using [single table inheritance](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html).

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :callback

  private 
  def callback
    puts "executing parent callback"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  before_save :callback

  private 
  def callback
    puts "executing child callback"
  end
end
```

I'd like for both the Parent's `callback` and the Child's `callback` to fire whenever I save a record, but I can't get this behaviour to work.  At the moment, when I save a Child, only the callback defined in that class runs.

The [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) say that parent callbacks should be automatically triggered when child classes are operated on (see the section on "Inheritable callback queues").  This isn't happening in my code.

Does anyone know why not?

Comment: wouldn't they overwrite one another since they are named the same? and should the method name be :parentCallback, :childCallback instead of just callback?

Comment: Ah.  Ok, so I never actually ran the code with callbacks named `parentCallback` and `childCallback`.  I changed the callback names quickly when I pasted the code into S.O. because I (stupidly) thought it would make the question more readable.

Comment: In the code I actually ran, both callbacks were just named `callback`.  I've just edited the question to reflect that.  And THAT WAS THE PROBLEM!  I guess the two identically named callbacks were overwriting each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried doing it this way? Method names are overwriting one another.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :parent_callback

  private 
  def parent_callback
    puts "executing parent callback"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  before_save :child_callback

  private 
  def child_callback
    puts "executing child callback"
  end
end
```